# How can I execute a script on a remote machine over ssh but source local files

Tags: linux, macos, mac, bash, ssh

I have a local script I want to run on a remote machine without copying it to the machine so I'm using:
ssh user@remote < local-script.sh

This works but if I add a source statement in local-script.sh to source another file e.g. `source ./another-local-script.sh`, when local-script.sh runs on the remote it's looking for the sourced file on the remote. Is there any way to solve this so that it resolves the sourced files locally first?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this transparently.

You can mangle your bash script to get files from your local machine using reverse tunnel, before sourcing them, but it is not much clean.

Much better is just to transfer all files you need and then run them as this:

```
scp local-script.sh another-script.sh user@remote
ssh user@remote local-script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

With a restricted set of input files that you control the contents of, you can
use `awk` or similar to replace the `source` command in the stdin stream by the sourced file. For example,

```
desource <local-script.sh | ssh user@remote
```

where desource is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '$1=="source" && NF>=2 {
      file = $2; while((getline <file)>0)print $0
      close(file); next
}
{ print }' "$@"
```

This just matches lines whose first word is "source" and takes the
2nd word as the file to insert. `getline` reads a line from that file
(into $0) and returns 0 on end-of-file. The `print` line just copies
through the non-matching lines.

Obviously, this is highly limited in its application, and for example
will need some work to recurse if the included file also has
`source` commands.

---

alternative getline with a variable instead of $0:

```
while((getline inp <file)>0)print inp
```

---

alternative script using `sed`. It reads the file twice, so usage needs
the filename (drop the "<" i.e.: `desource local-script.sh | ssh user@remote`)

```
#!/bin/bash
file=${1?}
cmd=$(  sed -n '/^[ \t]*source[ \t]/{=;s///;p}' <$file |
    sed  '/^[0-9]/{N;s/\n\(.*\)/{r \1;d;}/}' |
    tr ';' '\012' )
sed "$cmd" <$file
```

This uses sed a first time to match the `source` lines, print out
the line number (=) and leave just the filename (s/// reuses same pattern).
The 2nd sed takes the line number, appends the next line (N) and 
replaces the newline and following filename (.* is rest of line) by 
what will become a sed command to read the wanted file and delete the original line. The `tr` converts the semi-colons in the command to
newlines. The resulting command is given to a third sed on the original file.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, although I couldn't get your example to work - I'm getting empty lines where the replacement text should be. I'm not bothered about recursion btw.

Comment: I'm using awk on fedora 22. I edited my answer with a possible alternative use of `getline` via a variable. Does you awk man page give any details on `getline`?

Comment: sorry I probably should've stated that I'm running this on Mac OS X to ssh to a linux box. The awk man page does mention getline
```
       The  ``function''  getline sets $0 to the next input record from the current input file; getline <file sets $0 to the next record from file.  getline x sets variable x instead.
       Finally, cmd | getline pipes the output of cmd into getline; each call of getline returns the next line of output from cmd.  In all cases, getline returns 1  for  a  successful
       input, 0 for end of file, and -1 for an error.
```

Comment: awk looks similar to mine. Do you get 1 empty line for each line in the sourced file? Does your filename have any special characters in it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help @meuh but as I couldn't get your examples working on Mac OS X I came up with a function that does the job, although I'm sure many of you could improve on this:

```
# desource - substitute source statements in file with contents from sourced file
function desource {
  if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "Invalid file: $1"
    return
  fi
  declare tmp
  while read -r line; do
    if [ "${line:0:1}" == '#' ]; then continue; fi
    file=$(echo "$line" | perl -nle 'print $1 if m{(?>source )(.+)}' | sed 's|"||g')
    if [ -n "$file" ]; then
      case "${file:0:1}" in
        '/') ;;
        '~') ;;
        '$') ;;
          *) file="$(cd `dirname $1` && pwd)/$file"
      esac
      file=$(echo "$file" | sed "s|~|$HOME|" | sed "s|\$HOME|$HOME|")
      file="$(cd `dirname $file` && pwd)/$(basename $file)"
      if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        tmp="$tmp\n$(cat $file)"
      else
        echo "Invalid file: $file"
        return
      fi
    else
      tmp="$tmp\n$line"
    fi
  done < "$1"
  echo -e "$tmp"
}
```

Basically it reads through the file line by line inserting each line into a variable called tmp. If the line contains a source statement it gets the filename, resolving the absolute path to the file (and assumes any relative paths to be relative to the script passed in). It has checks to make sure the files exist and then adds the contents from those files into the tmp variable in place of the source statements.